# Handle onclick form submission success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form that when submits sends an email..pretty simple. 
But what I am trying to do is when the form is submitted and it is successful the JQM dialog box is closed. The way the form submits is through a regular button in the form with an onclick attribute.

```
  <input type="button" onclick="$('#emailReportForm').submit();" id="SubmitReport"value="EmailReport" data-theme="b" data-icon="check">
```

Where and How would I go about handling the success would I do that in the  onclick="$('#emailForm').submit(HERE);"

or would it be a more proper way to handle it another way?

Comment: Consider making a jsfiddle of a basic example of your fuller code. This way, people will find it easier to help you =]

Comment: I updated it to show the whole button, it just submits the form to a php file nothing special I just want to know how to handle the success of the form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *jQuery* you don't need what do you demonstrate, just use the callback function of the event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#emailForm').submit(function(event){
      // Do what do you want onsubmit here
   })
})
```

Comment: You are welcome and this is the beauty of programming: Simplicity!